# database error in codeigniter 3.0.1

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `id` = '0bc6ecedf769fe4ccd8199bd7bc76c15369c7419'' at line 2

SELECT `data` WHERE `id` = '0bc6ecedf769fe4ccd8199bd7bc76c15369c7419'

Filename: libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php

Line Number: 160
```

i've no idea how this error is coming, all i did was copied my models, controllers, helpers and views from CI 2.2 to CI 3.0.1

my session config looks like this

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

and these are my database settings

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'host',
    'username' => 'admin',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'db_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: you should try to upgrade 2.2 to 3 instead of coping files..

Comment: SELECT data `FROM table_name` WHERE id = '0bc6ecedf769fe4ccd8199bd7bc76c15369c7419' That's wasn't codeigniter fault.

Comment: @RubahMalam this is session table, so how can i control it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;` was set to `null` instead of `table name`